# TypeError: in scripting.executeScript(scripting.ScriptInjection injection): No matching signature. Chrome ext to save certain class of website html

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension

I am coding a simple extension to save the html code of a certain class in a website when clicked from the extensions menu in Chrome. Everything works successfully when I tested my code in the Chrome Developer Console, however when I try to fit it to an extension, it doesn't work.

```
Error handling response: TypeError: Error in invocation of scripting.executeScript(scripting.ScriptInjection injection, optional function callback): No matching signature.
```

My code is below:

manifest.json

```
{
    "name": "AOPS Saver",
    "version": "1.1",
    "manifest_version": 3,
    "description": "Saves current AOPS problem to file",

    "action": {
        "default_title": "???",
        "default_popup": "popup.html"
    },

    "permissions": [
        "scripting",
        "activeTab"
    ]
}
```

popup.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>My Extension</title>
    <script src="popup.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <button id="execute">Execute</button>
  </body>
</html>
```

popup.js

```
function saveToFile(text, filename) {
  var blob = new Blob([text], {type: 'text/plain'});
  var url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
  var a = document.createElement('a');
  a.href = url;
  a.download = filename;
  a.click();
}

  // Get the current tab's URL
chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function(tabs) {
  let tabID = tabs[0].id;
  let tabURL = tabs[0].url

  // Get the tab's content
  if (tabURL == 'https://artofproblemsolving.com/alcumus/problem'){
    chrome.scripting.executeScript( {target: {tabId: tabID}}, {
      code: 'document.documentElement.outerHTML'}, function(result) {
      // Check for elements with the class "alc-solution-text"
      let doc = new DOMParser().parseFromString(result[0], 'text/html');
      let elements = doc.getElementsByClassName('alc-solution-text');
      var str = elements[0]
      var str = str.innerHTML
      var container = $('<div>').html(str);
      // replace LaTeX images with alt text 
      container.find('img').replaceWith(function() { return this.alt; })
      var strAlt = container.html();
      var container = document.getElementById("page-wrapper");
      var div = document.createElement("div");
      div.className = "my-class";
      div.innerHTML = strAlt;
      container.appendChild(div);
      // Save to file
      saveToFile(div.innerText,'problems.txt')
      },
)};
});
```

Comment: Do you know what "no matching signature" means? If not, see [Signature (functions)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Signature/Function) and [chrome.scripting.executeScript](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/scripting/#method-executeScript)

Comment: No, I don't know what "no matching signature" means. I took a look at the links you sent. Is the problem that I must pass a "ScriptInjection" object?

Comment: @ThomasMueller If so, how do I pass my code into chrome.scripting.executeScript?

Comment: Use `func: ()=>document.documentElement.outerHTML`

Comment: To replace ```code: 'document.documentElement.outerHTML'```.?

Comment: Yes. As you can see in the documentation there's no `code` for this API.

Comment: I replaced ```code: 'document.documentElement.outerHTML'}``` with ```func: ()=>document.documentElement.outerHTML```. The same error still occurs, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: You probably look at the old error. Click the `clear all` button and use the correct devtools: right-click inside the popup and select "inspect" in the menu.

Comment: It can also mean that there's another mistake or a typo. Set a breakpoint on executeScript line in devtools and inspect each parameter.